# practical app to do screenshots with voiceover on windows and/or linux

Tags: linux, windows, screenshot

Does anyone knows what package(s) is suitable to do:

- pressing `PrintScr` (or any other button) making screenshot and starts recording from mic
- pressing `PringScr` again stops recording from mic
- files are saved into some directory with timestamps to be latter renamed. Picture and audio file to have the same file name to simplify playback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried google?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot

Under Linux, you'd look [at X11 capture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot#X_Window_System)

Sound can be done through a number of applications. Something as simple as *cat /dev/... > file* might suffice, although using **[sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)** is a far better choice.  (Sox includes **play** and **rec** command line utilities, as well as audio conversion and numerous other tools.  It's commonly found already installed on Linux systems.)

Date stamping files is as easy as **date** in a simple **tcsh** or **bash** script.

The Printscreen button is close to impossible.  Keyboard events are redirected to the currently active process (window).  You might be able to trigger (intercept) something through your X11 window manager.  Maybe.  Otherwise you are looking at the kernel.

You could always hook up some other hardware, like a second mouse, and write software to listen for it.  Or run a simple GUI application, or even command-line, at the border of your screen, and use ImageMagick utilities to trim that portion of your screen off.

Though a far easier solution is to run it on a second computer, networked to (ssh'ing into) the first.  For example:

```
(Everything is done on computerB.)
(convert is part of ImageMagick.)

machineB %  ssh machineA
machineA %  echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
machineA %  setenv DISPLAY machineA:0
machineA %  rm tmp.root.xwd
machineA %  xwd -root > tmp.root.xwd
machineA %  convert tmp.root.xwd  image.`date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S`.gif
```

Caveat:  On machineA, on the actual machineA, you might need to type ***xhost +machineA*** first.

Comment: Thanks for hint. After reading wiki page I landed to the answer on my question for windows: wink (from http://www.debugmode.com/wink/download.htm). It makes slides grouped into project and looks like it may take voice notes -- EXACTLY what want. Andrei